# recvfrom() hangs when I try to get time from NTP server

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ntp

I'm currently figuring out why my recvfrom() doesn't return anything.
I've suspected whether socket or NTP Ip address is wrong, but both seems right so far.

The following is the code:

```
    int sntp_client(ST_VOID)

{
    struct sockaddr_in saddr, myaddr;
    struct timeval tv, tp;
    int sntp_fd=-1;
    int len;
    unsigned int pkt_len;
    fd_set readfds;
    ST_CHAR hostname[16];

    sprintf(&hostname[0], "%d.%d.%d.%d", SNTP_IP.m_dsIPAddr.m_u8IP[0], SNTP_IP.m_dsIPAddr.m_u8IP[1]
                                , SNTP_IP.m_dsIPAddr.m_u8IP[2], SNTP_IP.m_dsIPAddr.m_u8IP[3]);

    // sntp ip 가 0.0.0.0 즉, 설정되지 않으면 시각동기를 하지 않는다.
    if(!strcmp(hostname, "0.0.0.0"))
    {
        printf("host ip error - 0.0.0.0\n");
        return -1;
    }
  
    // sntp 서버 ip 가져오기
    if((len = strlen(hostname)) <= 0)
    {
        printf("sntp : get host name error\n");
        return -1;
    }

  
    // socket 생성
    bzero((char *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)); 
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port   = htons(SNTP_SPORT);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);

    if((sntp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("sntp make socket error\n");
        return(sntp_fd);
    }
  
    bzero((char *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)); 
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(3030); 
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  
    if(bind(sntp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("sntp bind socket error\n");
        
        close(sntp_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Fill in the request packet */
    bzero((char *)&pkt, sizeof pkt);


    // 서우현 박사에 의하면 client에서 txtime을 0으로 셋팅하면 sntp 규격에 어긋나므로 
    // IED의 현재 시간을 넣는다. 
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

    pkt.txtime[0] = tp.tv_sec + JAN_1970;
    pkt.txtime[1] = tp.tv_usec * 4295;          

    
    pkt.livnmode = 0x1b;        /* version 1, mode 3 (client) */

 
    // send request packet to server
    if((len=sendto(sntp_fd, (char *)&pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0, 
                    (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr))) != sizeof(pkt))
    {
        printf("sntp service sendto() error\n");
        
        close(sntp_fd);
        return -1; 
    }
  
    //read reply packet from server
    pkt_len = sizeof(pkt);


    // montavistadpsms FD_ZERO가 꼭 있어야 한다. 
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sntp_fd, &readfds);  // FD_SET 메크로 사용
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    // select는 이벤트가 발생하기 전까지 block(대기)
    if(select(sntp_fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv)) 
    {
        if((len = recvfrom(sntp_fd, (char *)&pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0,
                                (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, &pkt_len)) != sizeof(pkt))
        {
            printf("sntp service recvfrom error\n");
            
            close(sntp_fd);
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //perror("ntp : select timeout\n");
        close(sntp_fd);
        return -1; 
    }


    // diebu add - 2019.12.31.
    // livnmode는 leap indicator(2bit) + version number(3bit) + mode (3bit) 이다. 
    // 여기서 leap indicator가 synchronize에 관련된다.
    // 정상 : 0x8A, ClockFailure : 0x4A, ClockNotSynchronize : 0x2A
    if((pkt.livnmode & 0xC0) == 0x00)
    {
        SntpTimeQuality = SNTP_TIME_GOOD;
    }
    else
    {
        // diebu modified - 2020.05.15. : SNTP_CLOCK_NOT_SYNCHRONIZED -> SNTP_CLOCK_FAILURE
        // 시각동기는 됬지만, synch가 맞지 않음 - clock not synchronized 
        // GPS등과 연결이 안된 시간을 의미..
        SntpTimeQuality = SNTP_CLOCK_FAILURE;
    }
    

    // STB는 UTC 시간 그대로 받는다.
    tv.tv_sec = ntohl(pkt.txtime[0]) - JAN_1970;
    tv.tv_usec = ntohl(pkt.txtime[1]/4295);         //  --> usec을 만들기 위해 
    
    settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    
    if(sntp_fd > 0)
        close(sntp_fd);

    return SD_TRUE;
}
```

As you can see in the code, I'm skipping the part by calling select() function.
However, I'd like to get the NTP time to synchronize.

I'm using the following pkt struct

```
struct 
{
    unsigned char livnmode, stratum, poll, prec;
    unsigned long delay, disp, refid;
    unsigned long reftime[2], origtime[2], rcvtime[2], txtime[2];
}pkt;
```

And I'm using '203.248.240.140' as the NTP server.

It'd be great if any network guru can help me out!!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return anything"? How can it not return anything? Also, did you confirm `sizeof(pkt)` is what you expect? If there's padding between `prec` and `delay`, your code won't work.

Comment: Also, `select` returns -1 on error, which your code interprets as success.

Comment: Don't bind to a specific IP address. BInd to 0.0.0.0.